# TypeScript files display two sets of inlay hints

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prisma

Using Visual Studio Code v1.70.1, with Typescript 4.9-dev.20220815

Here is my `settings.json` configuration for inlay hints:

```json
"typescript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "all",
"typescript.inlayHints.enumMemberValues.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.suppressWhenTypeMatchesName": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.functionLikeReturnTypes.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.parameterTypes.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.propertyDeclarationTypes.enabled": true,
"typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": true,
```

In `.tsx` files, this works as intended, producing one inlay hint with the styling I have defined:

`Header.tsx`

[image: Inlay hints working correctly]

However, in regular `.ts` files, two sets of inlay hints are produced where there should only be one, with on with the correct styling and one without:

[image: two inlay hints]

Disabling inlay hints entirely with `editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"` removes the ones with the correct styling, bu the erroneous hints are still there. Upon creating a new files this does not change either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was being caused by having another extension (specifically TypeScript Hero), which was also trying to add inlay hints. Removing the extension leaves just the built-in inlay hints.